# “who/w” command fails to list active user logged in from SSH client session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, users, administration

I (logged in as "user1", has root access) was following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622) to experiment with kicking a client ssh session logged in as "user2" (has no root access), connected from the same network from a laptop. The results of the `who -u` command showed both "user1" and "user2"

```
 15:15:59 up  2:03,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.09
user1     :0           2020-03-28 13:59   ?          4232 (:0)
user2   pts/1        2020-03-28 14:40   .         13155 (192.168.1.15)
```

I then did

```
sudo kill -9 13155
```

to assumingly kill their ssh session.

But not only did it not work (the terminal connected using ssh from my laptop as user 2 still has an active SSH session and is able to run commands), the new results of `who` don't show that running ssh session anymore!!!!

```
user1     :0           2020-03-28 13:59   ?          4232 (:0)
```

Am I misunderstanding how `who` and  `kill` commands work? `who` should list all logged in/active users. But clearly it doesn't as user2 is logged in but not listed by `who`.

I am willing to run any (well.. not literally ANY ;) ) commands and share the output with you to help me figure this out.

Comment: The `who` command just displays the content of the `/var/run/utmp` file. No more no less. See my comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484651/#comment889771_484651), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489924/how-can-i-run-a-process-as-its-owner-or-become-its-owner-without-logging-in#comment898366_489924) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556208#comment1033198_556208). Check if that ssh process is still running with `pgrep -a <pid>` or `ps <pid>`.

Comment: only `ps <pid>`, sorry